# Cannot install Ubuntu 12.04 on a Sony VAIO PCG-Z1RA due to features missing in the CPU for this kernel

Tags: 12.04, system-installation, vaio, sony

I'm trying to install Ubuntu Desktop 12.04 on a Sony VAIO laptop - model PCG-Z1RA, but it cannot install from disk. It says that there are features missing in the CPU for this kernel. The CPU is a Pentium M processor 1.50 GHz. Is there an earlier version that I should try?

Comment: Why it doesn't allow to do so? In versions later you won't have any support..

Answer (score 0):

Your CPU/GPU probably can't support the newer graphics APIs needed for Unity.

Try [lubuntu](http://www.lubuntu.net/) or [xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/).  They are lighter, require less resources, and should install.